# jqPlot - Label and Tick text overlap

Tags: label, jqplot, overlap

I'm trying to display ticks and label together on Y axis but the texts seem to be overlapping between the label and ticks:

[image: overlapped!]

Any idea how to move the label more to the left?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, silly of me.

I did not include jqplot CSS file properly. it was pointing to wrong directory.

Comment: You should accept your answer as the correct answer so that others know that this problem is solved